# Meu aplicativo só recebe notificações enquanto esta aberto

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Tenho um app q deve receber push messages mesmo com ele fechado.
no meu manifesto criei um serviço como descrito na doc do google:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="br.com.melhordosgames.apk.MyApplication">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-4163815586680581~5850909744"/>
    <activity
        android:name="br.com.melhordosgames.apk.Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="br.com.melhordosgames.apk.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity
        android:name="br.com.melhordosgames.apk.Ler_Post"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity
        android:name="br.com.melhordosgames.apk.Ver_game"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

    <service android:name="br.com.melhordosgames.apk.services.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="br.com.melhordosgames.apk.model.Sincronismo" />
    <receiver android:name=".Autostart"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Na minha classe eu estendo ela normal para o firebase message service

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
```

e tenho um `onMessageReceive` dentro dessa classe para emitir a notificação

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
```

Só que isso só funciona com o app aberto ou em segundo plano.
Não funciona, por exemplo, se o celular foi reiniciado ou se o app foi fechado.

Já olhei a documentação achei um monte de coisa por ai mas muito complexo não consegui implementar, alguém poderia me explicar como funciona isso para eu entende ronde estou errando?

Answer (score -2):

Para garantir que o app reinicie, acho que você pode utilizar esta permissão:
[android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)

Acho que seu código deveria ser algo assim:

```
<service android:name="br.com.melhordosgames.apk.services.FirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:directBootAware="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
         android:stopWithTask="false"
         android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
         android:directBootAware="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Isso deve garantir que o aplicativo continue recebendo mensagens de push mesmo após o reinício do dispositivo.

Comment: editei a pergunta com todo meu manifesto

Comment: mesmo assim nao funciona

Answer (score -3):

Para receber push notifications mesmo com o app fechado, você precisa fazer o seguinte:

Inscrever-se no serviço de push notification do Firebase na classe que extende a sua classe Application. Isso vai garantir que você receba notificações mesmo quando o app estiver fechado

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("all");
```

Adicionar o seguinte código no seu arquivo AndroidManifest.xml para garantir que o serviço de push notifications do Firebase inicie junto com o aplicativo:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

No seu método onMessageReceived, você precisa criar uma notificação para ser exibida ao usuário. Isso pode ser feito usando a classe NotificationCompat.Builder. Aqui está um exemplo de como criar uma notificação:

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Espero que isso ajude! Qualquer dúvida adicional, sinta-se à vontade para perguntar.

Comment: infelizmente se fechar o app ou reiniciar o celular só isso não resolve. meu app já faz isso dessa forma q vc explicou

Answer (score -3):

Você tem uma `filtro de intent` na sua configuração. Segun documentação a opção `android:exported` deve ser `true` nesse caso [1].

Em documentação:

> Se uma atividade no app incluir `filtros de intent`, defina esse elemento como `"true"` para permitir que outros apps a iniciem. Por exemplo, se a atividade for a principal do app e incluir a category `"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"`.

O mesmo informação é em StackOverflow (inglês) em [2].

Por padrão, algo ainda deve acontecer mesmo sem essa opção [3], mas o próprio manipulador do programa não funciona sem a configuração.

[1] [mais informações de opção android:exported](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=pt-br)

[2] [resposta à pergunta em StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868874/firebase-push-notifications-not-received-if-app-is-closed)

[3] [uma outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675999/can-firebase-messaging-services-can-be-androidexported-false)

Comment: o exported True é no service ou no filter ?

Comment: Donde você tem o exported false, primeiro codigo em seu pergunta.

Comment: obrigado vou mudar e testar.

Comment: Fiz o que você sugeriu e não funcionou :(. Teria alguma outra coisa q posso verificar ?

Comment: Você tem o código implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-directboot:20.2.0' no configuração Gradle? Você precisa disso por usar o DirectBoot. Mais em: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: tenho sim inclusive peguei o ex que tem neste link